# How to Disable or Enable Action Bar Sub Menu Items on other Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, submenu

I am making a app after Login my Login submenu item should be disable until the person is logout, after logout, Login item should be enable again!!!

> My main activity contains a Action bar is it possible to enable or
>   disable my code in Login Activity?

i have tried a code but didn't achieve any response on the basis of getstatus  item should be disable !!

**Login Activity Code**

```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    if (getstatus==1) {
        removeSomeItems(menu);
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"logout called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

protected void removeSomeItems(Menu menu){
    MenuItem Overflow = menu.findItem(R.id.action_login);
    Overflow.setVisible(false);  // I want this item to be available eventually

    menu.removeItem(R.id.action_logout); // I want this item to be unavailable for this activity
}
```

Can any one suggest me proper way to achieve this scenario ?

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: i have already solve my issue :) @Kishor Joshi